# SDL2: how to have both a SDL2 Menu and an OpenGL context?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I am trying to design a SDL2 application which has a main menu (created with a couple of SDL2 textures) with a couple of options.

Whenever one of those options is clicked, an OpenGL context should appear, either replacing the current window, or by creating a new one (and hiding the current one, which has the main menu). At a later time, after an event (for example, pressing a keyboard key), the menu should appear again.

The problem is: whenever I create an OpenGL context in the SDL_Window object which has the main menu, it seems impossible to restore the menu later on. It doesn't get rendered.

**The question is: is it possible to have both sdl texture elements and an opengl context in the same window? Not at the same time, of course: I want to use one of them at a time, replacing one with another.**

If the answer is yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I've found out that this is not really possible. After initializing OpenGL from within SDL, you cannot use any SDL drawing capabilities anymore: you either have to stick with OpenGL for all of your menus, or use SDL for them only once (=before initializing OpenGL).

SDL becomes responsible practically only for events, then.